# Usage of getSelectedNavigationItem throws "Unable to find Lightning Console App" when using Sales Console

Tags: lightning, api, navigation

I try to get the Selected Navigation Item in the Salesforce Navigation Bar. I have a lightning record page with a recordId, and on init I have written this code:

Lightning Page:

```
<lightning:navigationItemAPI aura:id="navigationItemAPI"/>
```

Controller:

```
helper.getSelectedNavigationItem(component, event, helper);
```

Helper:

```
getSelectedNavigationItem : function(component, event, helper) {
    var navigationItemAPI = component.find("navigationItemAPI");
    navigationItemAPI.getSelectedNavigationItem().then(function(navItem) {
        console.log('navItem '+navItem);
    });
}
```

The component is implemnented on the Case record page. When I navigate to the Navigation Item "Case" I get the error:

> "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to find Lightning Console App"

What is the issue here? How else would I be able to detect when a user changes Items in the App Navigation Bar?

Thanks!

Comment: you are using this on console app right?

Comment: Yes, I found out it works for the Service console, but not for the Sales Console...